# Wordpress permalink 'not found on this server'

Tags: wordpress

I just **moved a Wordpress** site to new host. But when I go to any page except the HOME page, I got this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /about was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at 176.xx.yy.zz Port 80
```

I changed the Permalink setting to Default which make the URL looks like `mysite.com/?page_id=5` and the page shows up fine. So the problem is not in my code.

My first guess is `mod_rewrite` isn't enabled. But `phpinfo()` tells me that `mod_rewrite` is loaded properly.

My **.htaccess** is generated automatically and looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta-test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /beta-test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to edit your Apache `http.conf` file and

change `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

to    `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

On versions of Apache2 where http.conf is no longer present (i.e. ubuntu) you can use the command a2enmod rewrite to enable the module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the `mod_rewrite` is shown on `phpinfo()`, it should already be uncommented right? I can't check the `http.conf` cause I don't have access to it.

Comment: I have no httpd.conf or any file that loads #LoadModule rewrite_module. I grepped the entire server.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your .htaccess file is in place, this is most likely caused by the Apache rewrite module not being enabled on your new server.  On Ubuntu do this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this could be because of these three issues also.

1. AccessFileName .htaccess is commented in your apache config.
2. AllowOverride ALL is not mentioned in your apache config for wordpress path.

Comment: For Apache 2.4.6, `AllowOverride None` is what's given in httpd.conf. I changed it to `AllowOverride All` and permalinks started to work.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a problem with the paths defined in the rewrite rule

Consider changing the following in the rewrite rules in the .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, run:

```
shell > a2enmod rewrite enable
```

If you are running on apache2.